# Nginx Неверное перенаправление на странице

Tags: nginx

При загрузке сайта кидает на /login, где говорится - Неверное перенаправление на странице. В чем может быть проблема?

```
server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:80;
        server_name localhost;
        root /var/www/site;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

       location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
       }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root /var/www/site;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

     }

    location ~ \.ht {
       deny all;
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/www/site/error.log;
    access_log /var/www/site/access.log;
}
```

Comment: А такой формат перенаправляет на нужную страницу, но пишет - Не верное перенаправление `
server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:80;
        server_name localhost;
        root /var/www/site;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

       location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
       }
`

Comment: Для `location ~ \.php$` установите корневую директорию

Comment: @Birdy установил root /var/www/site; изменений нет

Comment: Попробуйте так: `location ~ \.php$
{
 root /var/www/site;
 try_files $uri =404;
 fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
 fastcgi_index index.php;
 include fastcgi_params;
 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
`

Comment: @Birdy не помогло (

Comment: @Birdy хочу добавить, что все ссылки типа /login и тд - это роуты